# Trying to receive JSON in Spring controller for a post but it is coming in as null, how do I fix this?

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, post

I want to receive a JSONObject which I will later convert to my own Object within Spring. This is my controller code where objJson has null values:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, value ="postObj")
    public void postObj(@RequestBody JSONObject objJson){
        objCompleteService.insertObj(objJson);  
    }
```

I'm sending this with postman:

```
{"obj":"Test","objId":0,"definition":"post","languageId":0,"meaning":"post","submitterId":0}
```

and have set the Content-Type to application/json; charset=UTF-8

objJson is coming in as null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get JSON as map. `Paylod` is the whole JSON object. You can deserialize the object as you like. if you are sending raw data use `@RequestBody` but if you are sending form data use `@RequestParam`

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/postObj")
 @Timed
 public void postObj(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> payload){
     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(payload));
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! If anyone reading this needs future reference, I used ObjectMapper to deserialize.

Comment: @DessertsAndStuff I add that change also to anwser